# Generating pending image transforms stuck in process

Tags: image-transforms, cache, tasks

In the CMS the progress indicator for tasks is stuck and not completing its jobs. What can I do to resolve this?

[image: task indicators]

Comment: I'm getting that error also :/

Comment: Answer below is legit. I've had this happen a few times and it's the same scenario you have there (two image trans followed by a delete stale template cache). Coincidence or bug?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

More of a "How do I debug stuck tasks" answer, but it should help you.

Open up your craft_tasks table. You'll see one task in with a 'status' of 'running' and if you refresh the table several times, the 'currentStep' value for that task is no longer incrementing.  That's your stuck task.

Set that task's status to 'pending', and reload any page in the control panel to re-trigger the task.

If it gets stuck again, immediately go to your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder and check for a `phperrors.log` file.  If that exists, it will likely hold the error message for why the task is hung.

90% of the time, when a task gets stuck, it's because it has ran into some environmental limitation (PHP max_execution_time, memory_limit, etc.).

**Update:**

Just added a help article for this here: https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks

Comment: Is the max_execution_time php ini hardcoded into GD/Image.php? I keep running into `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/craft.lovindublin.com/craft/app/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Image.php on line 584` but my php_info says it's 300

Comment: Must be coming from something else then. If you're running things like FastCGI or nginx or Suhosin or mod_security, they each have their own (differently named) functionally equivalent settings.

Comment: Intriguing. Fix in new help text cleared it. Five weeks running (I was busy), no idea what caused. Probably GoDaddy, where this installation was client-stuck...thanks, Brad, as always.

Comment: Would be nice to have an option to do this manually from the CP. Unfortunately on our server there is no phpmyadmin installed which makes this task very inconvenient.

Comment: Just for posterity, this feature is now there, by Craft 2.5 release at least. You see a task is  running, click the rotating gezotz, may retry or delete it. Thank Brad, I am sure...

Comment: The tasks table in the latest versions of Craft is called just `tasks`.

Comment: @certainlyakey just depends on what you have your `craft/config/db.php`'s `tablePrefix` config setting set to.